# How to manage useReducer with other setState and how to manage unpure manipulation like DOM focus?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have read that reducer should be pure function.

I have then 2 questions : how to manage other setState, if they are linked with the reducer? And how to handle DOM manipulation like focus HTML element ?

To illustrate it, this is my code with an unpure reducer:

```
const ActDeclaration = () => {
   const [errors, setErrors] = useState({})
   const refPersonType = useRef()

   const reducer = (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
         case "internalNumber":
            return { ...newState, internalNumber: action.payload }
         case "profile": {
            setErrors({}) // HERE
            const errors = hasErrors(newState, setErrors)

            if (!isEmpty(errors)) {
               setErrors(errors) // HERE

               refPersonType.current.scrollIntoView({ // HERE
                  behavior: "smooth",
                  block: "start",
               })
            }
            return newState
         }
         default:
            return newState
      }
   }

   const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, {})
```

I use `setErrors` to modify a state variable which is responsible to show/manage errors.

Is that likely to make a side effect? Actually, does the setErrors in the reducer, triggers a re-render?

Manage errors state in the internal state of the reducer would be not ideal for me, because `setErrors` is also called by a submit function, which doesn't rely on the reducer, this is why I found that take errors apart was a good idea.

Second problem, the `ref` focus. I suspect also this is a side effect. How to handle it? I made it like that, because I have a button, which on click event, calls the dispatch function and so, the reducer function. So, reducer seemed to be an appropriate candidate to do the focus stuff.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a wrong place for `profile` action to check for error and do scroll in it at the same time.

You can do so outside the reducer within `useEffect` or within an event handler as there is no state manipulation going on for `profile`.